# Visual Studio 2015: @ color setting in Text Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2015

My existing Visual Studio environment setting has the problem for recognizing the Razor syntax "**@**", and it makes every @ syntax with terrible background color, like the image showing:

[image]

Does anyone know which "Display Item" name is for @ in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 0):

In Text Editor settings they all starts from "HTML Razor..." name. The one you need is named "HTML Razor Code Background".
Apart from the manual editing of all those items, you can just download a color scheme which seems best for you from studio styles website (studiostyl.es). You can also edit downloaded *.vssettings file, the item you need is called "RazorCode".
Have fun.